# Use apply in dataframe with arguments returns an error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
def mean_vectorizer(words, dimention, diction):
  return np.array([np.mean([diction[w] for w in words if w in diction] or [np.zeros(dimention)], axis=0)])

data['vector'] = data.apply(lambda x: mean_vectorizer(x['words'], 100, diction), axis=1)
```

The column `words` in dataframe has a list of words. The `diction` is a dictionary with a word as a key and an array with a fixed size as the value. What I try to do is to create a new column which will parse the list in each row, get the array for each word from the dictionary and calculate one single array with the average values of the rest.

Running the above code returns this error:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

However, if I run the code for a single line with the following code, it doesn't complain

```
words = data.iloc[0]['words']
np.array([np.mean([diction[w] for w in words if w in diction] or [np.zeros(dimention)], axis=0)])
```

Comment: Seems like you have an extra square brace: `axis=0)])`

Comment: What are the dimensions of the returned array? what happens, in your second example that works, if you try to set it to a single column in `data` : `data['new'] = np.array(...` Does it raise the same exemption?

Comment: @coldspeed without it I have a syntax error. It is the closing square bracket from the first np.array

Comment: Oh, I see that. What if you return `np.array([np.mean([diction[w] for w in words if w in diction] or [np.zeros(dimention)], axis=0)]).tolist()`

Comment: it does work with the `tolist()`, but now I realise that it returns a list inside a list. I just need to remove the `np.array` and keep just the `np.mean`